# How to organize nodes.pp file to group class/define?

Tags: puppet

How to group some class / define in the node.pp file?

```
node 'node1' {
        ntp { ntp:
            server_is => "node"
        }
        dns_resolv { dns:
            server_is => "node"
        }
}
```

And, I have some modules: "oracle rpm", "sshkey users", "kernel parameters", ... and I don't know how to group together an unique class, for example "oracle-base" which contains all of my previous modules, then, if I declare a node with "oracle-base", it would automatically configure my node for oracle's modules.

How did you do that?

Thanks !

Comment: See: [Learning Puppet — Modules and Classes](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/learning/modules1.html)

Answer (score 4):

Puppet Labs has some good documentation on this scenario here:

[Modules Fundamentals](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/modules_fundamentals.html)

Essentially, you put your manifest configuration inside a class definition. Then you "include classname" under your node or another class.